# How is user range error (URE) calculated/estimated in a basic receiver?

Tags: gps, position, rinex

For a basic receiver how can we estimate/calculate URE when the pseudorange observable is used? Assume that it is a single frequency (L1) receiver.

Is there any metric that can be used to estimate this error to some extent? i.e. does the receiver have any estimate of the quality of the signal other than from the elevation of the satellite and DOP. Is the signal-to-noise ratio (SNR) which appears in the RINEX observation file for each pseudorange of any use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SNR will not be of any use for UERE purposes.

What you are probably looking for is the residual error, which is the distance that the observed pseudorange differs from the calculated position.

How you obtain the individual residuals will be specific to the software or receiver you use to process the RINEX.